# Lost connection to MySQL server during query (max_allowed_packet=64M)

Tags: mysql

i already set the maximum timeout in workbench also in my.ini file in sql server max_allowed_packet=64M but the problem is the same
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

//this is my code on view

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `sales_gp_view` AS
    SELECT 
        `m_sales`.`date` AS `sales_date`,
        `m_sales`.`user` AS `cashier`,
        `m_sales`.`salesman` AS `salesman`,
        `m_sales`.`sold_to` AS `s_to`,
        `m_sales`.`address_to` AS `add_to`,
        `m_sales`.`date_updated` AS `date_updated`,
        `m_sales`.`branch_name` AS `branch_name`,
        `m_sales`.`si` AS `si`,
        `m_sales`.`remarks` AS `remarks`,
        `m_sales_items`.`quantity` AS `quantity`,
        `m_sales_items`.`name_id` AS `name_id`,
        `m_sales_items`.`price` AS `price`,
        `m_sales_items`.`name_code` AS `name_code`,
        `m_sales_items`.`name` AS `description`,
        `m_sales_items`.`total` AS `total`,
        `m_sales_items`.`invid` AS `invid`
    FROM
        (`m_sales`
        LEFT JOIN `m_sales_items` ON (((`m_sales`.`branch_id` = `m_sales_items`.`branch_id`)
            AND (`m_sales`.`branch_name` = `m_sales_items`.`branch_name`)
            AND (`m_sales`.`date_deleted` = ''))))
```

m_sales table has 150360 rows and m_sales_item has 281375 rows

Comment: Is there any error in mysql error log?

Comment: Yes, it shows "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
"

Comment: I didn't know if my query is incorrect or the mySql server .